# All logs being duplicated into apache error log

Tags: python, apache, logging, flask, mod-wsgi

I have a flask project with logging set up by a config file.
This works as desired when running locally but when I run it under apache wsgi all of the log messages (not just errors) are written to the error.log file set up in the vhost as well.

After some googling I found [this issue](https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/641) which I thought could be related and tried setting app.logger_name and calling app.logger but I'm still having the same issue.

config/logging.yaml: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/7n6v8nEb)

Vhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName myapp.com

        WSGIDaemonProcess myapp home=/var/www/vhosts/myapp/httpdocs
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/vhosts/myapp/httpdocs/myapp.wsgi

        <Directory /var/www/vhosts/myapp/httpdocs>
                WSGIProcessGroup myapp
                WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog /var/www/vhosts/myapp/logs/error.log
        CustomLog /var/www/vhosts/myapp/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

myapp.wsgi:

```
activate_this = '/var/www/vhosts/myapp/httpdocs/env/bin/activate_this.py'
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))

import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/vhosts/myapp/httpdocs')

from run_web import app as application
```

run_web.py:

```
import init
import logging
from web import app, api

init.add_to_syspath()

init.logging_conf()

# Flask removes all log handlers so our logs are written to the error log as well.
app.logger_name = "nowhere"
app.logger

logger = logging.getLogger('run_web')

logger.info('Starting web')

api.init()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logger.info('Flask running in debug mode')
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

init.logging_conf():

```
def logging_conf():
    with open('conf/logging.yaml', 'r') as yaml_file:
        logging_config = yaml.load(yaml_file)

    dictConfig(logging_config)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that writing to stdout writes to the Apache error log. I have opened a more relevant question: [How can I stop sys.stdout logging to apache error file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36449922/how-can-i-stop-sys-stdout-logging-to-apache-error-file)