# How can I stop sys.stdout logging to apache error file?

Tags: python, apache, logging, mod-wsgi

I have the Python `logging` library set up to log everything to my console handler. This works great in development so I can see my log messages without having to look through the files but in production all of the logs are being written to the apache error file.

Is this desired behaviour? Shouldn't `stderr` solely write to the error file?

The console handler set up in my `yaml` config file:

```
handlers:
  console:
    class: logging.StreamHandler
    formatter: precise
    filters: [request_id]
    stream: ext://sys.stdout
```

I have thought about only adding the console handler in debug mode, but I have lots of loggers with propagate set to `false`, so I would have to add the handler to each logger which defeats the point of my config file.

I have put the entire config file into [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/7n6v8nEb).

How can I stop `stdout` writing to the Apache error file and could this have adverse effects?

Answer (score 0):

You could use to log in a text file along with the standard output stream.
In development environment, it may help keeping both the handlers, file and std out. But you have to omit the standard output stream in production. I use google colab as a development environment; use your own logic to bypass `logger.addHandler(stream_handler)`.

```
def get_logger(logger_name, log_root, process_id, level=logging.INFO):
    """
    Creates the logger object, pour multiple level of logs in a text file
        resides at log_root with the name given by process_id.

    Args:
        logger_name: name of the logger object to identify
        log_root: file directory of the log files
        process_id: separate log file for each process / request / run
        level: log level; could be CRITICAL, ERROR, WARNING, INFO, DEBUG

    Returns:
        logger: the logger object

    Raises:
        ModuleNotFoundError: raised and passed; when in production

    Usage:
        logger = get_logger(project_name, log_directory, process_id)
        logger.info(f"inside driver function... time: {time.ctime()}")
        logger.warning(f"this should not happen.")
        logger.error(f"this is critical!")
    """
    logger = logging.getLogger(logger_name)
    if not logger.hasHandlers():
        logger.setLevel(level)

        formatter = logging.Formatter("[%(asctime)s] [%(levelname)s] [%(filename)s:%(lineno)s] %(message)s",
                                    "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

        file_handler = logging.FileHandler(f'{log_root}/{process_id}')
        file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)

        stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
        stream_handler.setFormatter(formatter)

        logger.addHandler(file_handler)

        try:
            import google.colab
            logger.addHandler(stream_handler)
        except ModuleNotFoundError as me:
            pass

    return logger
```